# Regex in JavaScript - Match a string like "ABC12"

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match the following string using regular expression in JavaScript?

1. Has a total of 5 characters
2. First 3 charaters are capital letters
3. Last 2 characters are only numbers

I have got this pattern, `[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}`, but seems that it's still missing something.

Comment: What do you think it's missing?

Comment: Look at: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
var regexp = /^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$/
```

Otherwise, substrings will also match (like `ABC12` within `xyzABC1234`).

- `^` means "start of string"
- `$` means "end of string"

Comment: What's ^ and $ for? Can you explain a bit further here. thanks

Comment: ^ indicates start of string and $ indicates end.

Comment: Those are the 'anchors'. ^ means 'start of string' and $ means 'end of string'

Comment: Sure, I've also included a link to a good tutorial.